# Is possible to use regex in Sort Key on a on dynamodb query?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to make a query like this.

val dynamoDB = DynamoDB(dynamoDBConfig.amazonDynamoDB())
val table: Table = dynamoDB.getTable("music")

```
    val spec = QuerySpec()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("artist = :_artist and begins_with(title, :_title)")
            .withValueMap(ValueMap()
                    .withString(":_artist", "Guns n' Roses")
                    .withString(":_title", "*to the Jungle")
            )
```

and this results in a list of music containing a music with title "Welcome **to the Juntle**"

Comment: No, you can’t. To support that type of usecase you will generally need to look at a complimentary solution, such as Elastic Search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, regex is not supported in [Key Condition Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions).